# Problems with FunctionPeriod

Tags: functionperiod

Why does `FunctionPeriod[Sin[x],x]` give the correct answer

(* $2 \pi$ *)

but `FunctionPeriod[.1 Sin[x],x]` give the incorrect answer

(* $0$ *) ?

Comment: `FunctionPeriod[1/10  Sin[x], x]`

Comment: Thanks!... but the original question remains.

Comment: It is not a question of amplitude either since `100.` gives a `0` answer as well. Apparently it needs a *non-Real* multiplier; something that is not indicated on the doc page. I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Comment: Do you know such an example where `FunctionPerio[[Rationalize[f[x],0],x]` does not work?

Comment: Oh... good idea.  Seems to work on all my relevant functions.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that `FunctionPeriod` is quite fragile, and there are [multiple questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=FunctionPeriod) discussing its troubles. Internally, it calls a function from the ```Periodic`*``` namespace, but it is difficult to spelunk/debug, because its functions are locked.